# BIOS setup message appears every time I start my computer

Tags: bios

Whenever I start my computer with Windows XP on it, even from hibernating, I have to press <kbd>F2</kbd> so that it loads the default BIOS values.

The other option is pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter setup.

Earlier it used to load automatically, there was no need to press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

What's the solution to that problem?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to replace your [CMOS battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery).

How to change it (and if it's even possible) will depend on your specific hardware.